# SELECT an attribute from a table but need conditions met in other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, entity

Okay so I'm new to database so excuse my lack of knowledge please. Ive looking for answers online and I dont quite understand what I need to do. I have to find out which plane is flying a specific flight given the date, time, route.
These are the attributes for each entity

### airplaneid

*airplaneid* -PK

planetype

### dflights

*flightnumber*-PK

*Flightdate*-PK

FlightDuration

## Flight

*flightnumber*-PK

airportID

Comment: please show what you have tried

Comment: There doesn't appear to be enough information in the specified relations to produce the specified tuples. That is, there doesn't appear to be any relationship (common values) between the tuples in the **`airplaneid`** relation and the tuples in the other two relations. (This is where having some **example data** would be invaluable to help you gain an understanding of relational database theory. With the relations shown in the question, it's not possible to tell which plane is flying which route when.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to return the specified result from the relations shown.

There are no common values stored in the (unfortunately named) **`airplaneid`** entity relation, and the other two entity relations.

<strike>I'll put together an example of how it could be done...</strike>

You'd need to have `airplaneid` stored in another relation, along with `flightnumber` and `flightdate` in order to associate the two entities.